# Under what hypothesis on the domain is the X-ray transform/John transform operator bounded?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, integral-transforms, integral-geometry, inverse-problems

I asked this question on math stackexchange, without any reply yet.

Link:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401580/under-what-hypothesis-is-the-x-ray-transform-john-transform-operator-bounded

Could you please take a look?

Let $\mathcal{L}$=space of all lines $L$.
The X-ray transform is defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_transform $Xf:\mathcal{L}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by:
$Xf(L)=\int_{t \in L}f(t)|dt|$.

In this definition, the X-ray transform $Xf$ of a function $f$ is defined only for compactly supported continuous functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Note that $X:\mathcal{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)\to \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of continuous scalar valued functions on the set $\mathcal{L}$ of all lines L.

My questions are:
1) Under these conditions, is the transform operator $X$ bounded?

2) If we instead assume that $f$ is a rapidly decaying function, i.e., both $f, \nabla f \to 0$  at infinity, what can we say about the boundedness of $X$?

I'd very much appreciate a detailed explanation.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Continuity of $X$ depends on the norms (or other topologies) you put on your function spaces.
Let me give some examples.
You can find a discussion of the Radon transform and the X-ray transform in various spaces in [these lecture notes](https://rrschmidt.wordpress.com/inverse-problems-course-notes/).

**Example 1:**
$X:L^1(\mathbb R^d)\to L^1(\cal L)$ is continuous since
$$
\int_{L\in\cal L}\left|\int_Lf\right|
\leq
\int_{L\in\cal L}\int_L|f|
=
\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f|
$$
for a suitably scaled measure on $\cal L$.

**Example 2:**
$X:C_c(\mathbb R^d)\to C_c(\cal L)$ is continuous.
Let us define the map $h:\mathbb R^d\times S^{n-1}\to\cal L$ so that $h(x,v)$ is the line going through $x$ in direction $v$.
This map is continuous and $\operatorname{spt}(Xf)\subset h(\operatorname{spt}(f)\times S^{n-1})$ so $X$ indeed maps compactly supported functions to compactly supported functions.
If $f\in C_c(\mathbb R^d)$ and there is a compact convex set $K$ so that $Xf(L)=0$ whenever $L\cap K=\emptyset$, then $\operatorname{spt}(f)\subset K$ — this is Helgason's support theorem.
Knowing this, it should not be too hard to show continuity.

**Example 3:**
$X:C_c^k(\mathbb R^d)\to C_c^k(\cal L)$ is continuous for any $k\in\{1,2,\dots,\infty\}$.

**About decay at infinity:**
It seems to me that if $f\to0$ and $\nabla f\to0$ at infinity, then $Xf$ should have the same behaviour.
To make this rigorous, you need to specify what you want.

To play with the derivatives, observe that you can differentiate in $\cal L$ in essentially two kinds of directions: you can shift a line with constant direction or you can rotate a line around a point on the line.
In both cases the derivative of $Xf$ at $L\in\cal L$ is the integral of a derivative of $f$ along $L$ with constant or linearly growing weight.
Using this you can see, for example, that if $f$ and $\nabla f$ decay exponentially, so do $Xf$ and $\nabla Xf$.